# Как вывести в лог только некоторые записи?

Tags: delphi

Компонент mmLog (он же Memo лог) - используется в качестве вывода информации об обработанных файлах. Программа обрабатывает файлы и сохраняет информацию об обработанных файлах в **mmLog**.

**Проблема в том что:** В логе, выводиться информация и про - исходные файлы.

**То есть вот так:**

```
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\1.txt (Исходный файл)
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\2.txt (Исходный файл)
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_1.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_2.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_Копия_1.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_Копия_2.txt
```

**Вопрос:** Как вывести, в Memo, информацию - только об обработанных файлах, исключая исходные.

**То есть вот так:**

```
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_1.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_2.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_Копия_1.txt
C:\Users\Tatyana\Desktop\Test\Копия_Копия_2.txt
```

Код программы:

```
procedure TForm1.btStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  file_list: TStringList;
  i, j, countR, indexR: Integer;
  s, pathfile, flname1, flname2: string;
  f1, f2: textfile;
begin
................................................
  pathfile := '*.txt';
  file_list := TStringList.Create;
  // Получаем список файлов в директории и под директории
  findfile(edit1.Text + '\', pathfile, file_list);
  // отображаем файлы (Лог) в Memo //////////////////////// Вот тут лог
  mmLog.Text := file_list.Text;
  // Делаем проход по ФАЙЛАМ
  for i := 0 to file_list.Count - 1 do
  begin
    flname1 := file_list.Strings[i];
    flname2 := ExtractFileDir(flname1) + '\Копия_' + extractfilename(flname1);
.............................................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за компонент `mmLog`?

Если просто `TMemo`, то:

```
for i := 0 to file_list.Count - 1 do
begin
  flname1 := file_list.Strings[i];
  flname2 := ExtractFileDir(flname1) + '\Копия_' + extractfilename(flname1);

  mmLog.Lines.Append(flname2);
end;
```